# Python 3 - recognizing minus signs in a text string

Tags: string, replace

I'm using Python 3.5 and import a text file  as follows
with open(fn) as f:
    data = f.read()

I then notice that there's a space between the minus sign and the digits of a negative number (e.g. \n\t- 2.51\t). I have tried to close the gap by writing
data.replace('- ','-'), but nothing happens. Oddly enough, this works like a charm in a Python console, but not in code. How can I solve this problem?

Is this a Unicode issue? Is it possible that the - I type on my keyboard is different from the - in the file? If so, how can I tell the two -'s apart?

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 0):

I made an elementary error, and wrote

```
data.replace('- ','-'),
```

when I should have written

```
data = data.replace('- ','-').
```

As soon as I did this, the problem solved itself.